# swift using guard and typechecking in one line

Tags: swift

I like using guard and came across the situation where I want to use `where` for a typecheck as well:

```
guard let status = dictionary.objectForKey("status") as! String! where status is String else { ...}
```

xCode complains correctly that it's always true.

My goal is to have an unwrapped String after the guard in one line.

How can I do this?

Comment: so you just want to check it's a string?

Comment: Sorry, I also want to cast it, since I already know it's a String, through the `is String` statement

Comment: @lukas_o the answer below by "Shadow Of" is correct.

Comment: I recommend u read some documentation of [Swift](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID309)

Comment: @Fogmeister thank you for edit my answer of course, but it was more universal before. My thoughts was that people rarely use `NSDictionary` type in swift, so `dictionary` var probably can have `NSUserDefaults` type as well, thats why I keep `objectForKey` method.

Comment: I've edited to question, to make the point more clear. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably you want this?

```
guard let status = dictionary["status"] as? String else {
    // status does not exist or is not a String
}

// status is a non-optional String
```

Comment: Great, thank you! You were first, so I gonna give you the check.

Answer (score 2):

When you use `as! String!` you tell Swift that you *know* that the object inside your dictionary must be a `String`. If at runtime the object is not a `String`, you let Swift throw a cast exception. That is why the `where` part of your check is not going to fail: either the `status` is going to be a `String`, or you would hit an exception prior to the `where` clause.

You can do an optional cast instead by using `as?` operator instead of `as!`. Coupled with `guard let`, this approach produces

```
guard let status = dictionary.objectForKey("status") as? String else { ... }
... // If you reached this point, status is of type String, not String?
```